# Create a class that inherits a list of objects in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Coming from a .NET background, I used to make classes that looked a lot like this:

```
MyClass
Inherits List(Of SomeOtherClass)
```

I am getting smoked trying to do this in Objective-C. I am wanting to have a class that is a collection of UIImageViews.

I tried this, which is wrong (it inherits from NSArray):

```
- (id)init
{
    //I know I'm not using an imageview here, this was just a proof of concept
    self = [super initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnSideMenu"], nil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

The collection is a fixed size, so it won't need to be mutable. However, if using a NSMutableArray provides more syntactical sugar than I would not be opposed to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Objective-C doesn't have any features comparable to generics in .NET. You'll just want to use `NSMutableArray` instead.

Comment: Either use an NSArray or define a new class off of NSObject that contains the array pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks That seems to be the direction that will make the most sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a subclass for this is excessive. Subclasses should be used to add functionality to a super class. You should just make an NSMutableArray of UIImageViews

Comment: I think this with Hot Licks response entails the full answer.

Comment: You need to consider whether you want the original objects or copies.